# How to make google spreadsheet graphs responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, google-sheets, media-queries

```
<iframe height=468 width=1584 src="//docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hUgiZqpgjqqtpnYY6Q1IeoUYlpXlCRUeARpN3cWX87g/gviz/chartiframe?oid=2131305794" seamless frameborder=0 scrolling=no></iframe>
```

Even after changing width to 100%, it doesn't make it responsive. I am embedding this graph on WordPress website.

Comment: Please give us your wordpress website address so that we can see the issue in live action.

Comment: You can put both `width="100%"` and `style="max-width:100%"`. In your code, there's a fixed width...

Comment: @msbodetti URL - http://www.getcsr.com/index.php/256-2/

Comment: @Valentin Mercier http://www.getcsr.com/index.php/256-2/

Comment: I got one solution, but the problem in this is the value aren't dynamic they have manually added those values. Is there anyway to change it and use the values which are there in my google spreadsheet as in google spreadsheet my values will keep on changing from time to time. http://codepen.io/shoogledesigns/pen/BfLkA

Comment: Still interested in a solution to this?  I have one in mind but want to make sure it's still needed before I spend time on it.

Answer (score 5):

Put div around that iframe (as parent element), and set CSS "transform: scale(0.5)" to that div.

```
<div style="transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);">
<iframe ...>
</div>
```

It will resize whole frame, including its content.

Comment: I added a few more styles: `transform: scale(0.5, 0.5) translate(-50%, 0px); width: 200%;` to move it left a little and use the whole width. Otherwise it would also use less space.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a bit of looking around on the web for you and have several solutions. One of the most popular seems to be to use JQuery in order to resize the iFrame correctly.

A link to the script is found here: [jQuery Responsive iFrame's](http://npr.github.io/responsiveiframe/)

```
<!-- Activate responsiveness in the "child" page -->
<script src="/js/jquery.responsiveiframe.js"></script>
<script>
  var ri = responsiveIframe();
  ri.allowResponsiveEmbedding();
</script>

<!-- Corresponding code in the "parent" page -->
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.responsiveiframe.js"></script>
<script>
  ;(function($){          
      $(function(){
        $('#myIframeID').responsiveIframe({ xdomain: '*'});
      });        
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

From there just make the iFrame have an ID of `myIframeID` or simply change the text in the script above to accommodate this.

Should this not work for you I would suggest using my Google Search string to finding other possible solutions: [responsive iframe width](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=responsive%20iframe%20width)

Good Luck!

Comment: Hey can you tell me how to put this on a WordPress website. I have no ideas about it. As far as your second option goes, I tried a lot and didn't got any solution even after googling.

Comment: I got one solution, but the problem in this is the value aren't dynamic they have manually added those values. Is there anyway to change it and use the values which are there in my google spreadsheet as in google spreadsheet my values will keep on changing from time to time. http://codepen.io/shoogledesigns/pen/BfLkA